# MSSQL Database Slow after upgrading to SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, sql-server-2012

We are in the process of moving our large database from a local server (MSSQL 2000) to a SQL 2012 Server hosted on Amazon Web Services.

I created a new database from scratch on the new server, ran a script to create the tables, imported all the data and then ran SQL compare to build all the stored procedure and views etc.

A stored procedure when run on the local server took 2 mins but now running on SQL 2012 it's going over 30 mins and timing out.

I've rebuilt all the indexes and updated the statistics as well as running the stored procedure on the server rather than remotely but no difference.

Any suggestions?

## Update - More Info

Thanks for your replies

```
[Old Server] AMD Quad Codde 2376 2.29Ghz with 4GB Ram running Windows 2003  + SQL 2000
[New AWS Instance] Intel Xeon E5-2670 2.50Ghz with 30.5 GB Ram running Windows 2012 + SQL 2012

wait_type                           wait_time_s pct running_pct

DIRTY_PAGE_POLL                     23132.77    28.47   28.47

HADR_FILESTREAM_IOMGR_IOCOMPLETION  23131.66    28.47   56.95

SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS_SLEEP         23100.10    28.43   85.38

LATCH_EX                            4784.63     5.89    91.27

SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD                 1548.42     1.91    93.18

LCK_M_U                             1438.27     1.77    94.95

WRITELOG                            753.34      0.93    95.87
```

Comment: The comparisons are not very relevant. You went from unspecified physical hardware to an unspecified virtual machine with virtual disks, in an unspecified plan. The obvious answer is that you underprovisioned your VM. This isn't something that can be fixed by updating statistics

Comment: please add your existing specs  and also what are the issues you are seeing in a detailed manner..what are the wait types when the query is running on VM

Comment: Thanks for your replied

Comment: @Ham1979 did you set db, tempdb, log files initial size, filegrowth options? Also can tou post old execution plan and new one for this SP?

Answer (score 0):

You have to start from somewhere, analysing the server. As you claim that you've updated the stats/indexes, next is to see where it hurts. Use this widely used script for finding the wait stats so you can inhale the situation better.

```
WITH [Waits] AS
    (SELECT
        [wait_type],
        [wait_time_ms] / 1000.0 AS [WaitS],
        ([wait_time_ms] - [signal_wait_time_ms]) / 1000.0 AS [ResourceS],
        [signal_wait_time_ms] / 1000.0 AS [SignalS],
        [waiting_tasks_count] AS [WaitCount],
        100.0 * [wait_time_ms] / SUM ([wait_time_ms]) OVER() AS [Percentage],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [wait_time_ms] DESC) AS [RowNum]
    FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats
    WHERE [wait_type] NOT IN (
        N'CLR_SEMAPHORE',    N'LAZYWRITER_SLEEP',
        N'RESOURCE_QUEUE',   N'SQLTRACE_BUFFER_FLUSH',
        N'SLEEP_TASK',       N'SLEEP_SYSTEMTASK',
        N'WAITFOR',          N'HADR_FILESTREAM_IOMGR_IOCOMPLETION',
        N'CHECKPOINT_QUEUE', N'REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH',
        N'XE_TIMER_EVENT',   N'XE_DISPATCHER_JOIN',
        N'LOGMGR_QUEUE',     N'FT_IFTS_SCHEDULER_IDLE_WAIT',
        N'BROKER_TASK_STOP', N'CLR_MANUAL_EVENT',
        N'CLR_AUTO_EVENT',   N'DISPATCHER_QUEUE_SEMAPHORE',
        N'TRACEWRITE',       N'XE_DISPATCHER_WAIT',
        N'BROKER_TO_FLUSH',  N'BROKER_EVENTHANDLER',
        N'FT_IFTSHC_MUTEX',  N'SQLTRACE_INCREMENTAL_FLUSH_SLEEP',
        N'DIRTY_PAGE_POLL', N'SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS_SLEEP')
    )
SELECT
    [W1].[wait_type] AS [WaitType],
    CAST ([W1].[WaitS] AS DECIMAL(14, 2)) AS [Wait_S],
    CAST ([W1].[ResourceS] AS DECIMAL(14, 2)) AS [Resource_S],
    CAST ([W1].[SignalS] AS DECIMAL(14, 2)) AS [Signal_S],
    [W1].[WaitCount] AS [WaitCount],
    CAST ([W1].[Percentage] AS DECIMAL(4, 2)) AS [Percentage],
    CAST (([W1].[WaitS] / [W1].[WaitCount]) AS DECIMAL (14, 4)) AS [AvgWait_S],
    CAST (([W1].[ResourceS] / [W1].[WaitCount]) AS DECIMAL (14, 4)) AS [AvgRes_S],
    CAST (([W1].[SignalS] / [W1].[WaitCount]) AS DECIMAL (14, 4)) AS [AvgSig_S]
FROM [Waits] AS [W1]
INNER JOIN [Waits] AS [W2]
    ON [W2].[RowNum] <= [W1].[RowNum]
GROUP BY [W1].[RowNum], [W1].[wait_type], [W1].[WaitS],
    [W1].[ResourceS], [W1].[SignalS], [W1].[WaitCount], [W1].[Percentage]
HAVING SUM ([W2].[Percentage]) - [W1].[Percentage] < 95; -- percentage threshold
GO
```

I assume it is this option called “TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME” and is set using ALTER DATABASE command. For more details refer BOL at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403416(v=sql.110).aspx.
By just setting TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME to something different than 0 you're actually enabling the indirect checkpoint which is more efficient and brings optimization. Set it for example to 60 seconds and watch how your system behaves.